# Close accordion alike div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple code which shows 3 items

When I press the header  (`$(".fileHeader")`) , it should open then next element which is the next element (hidden div)  (`$(".LST_Documents")`)

sketch  :

[image]

[**JSBIN : it does work.**](http://jsbin.com/ituvok/3/edit)

Most important :

When I press on a `$(".fileHeader")`- i need to close all **other**  `$(".LST_Documents")` and **then**  ( that why i used `promise`) open the relevant `$(".LST_Documents")`.

The problem is (look at the pic) if i press again on the first `$(".fileHeader")`.
what is happening is that it closing and then re opening. and  **I want it to stay CLOSED**.

## P.S.

I could solve it with class ( `.rowOpen` or something like that) but I want to do it via JS/JQ only.

How can I enhance my code to work as expected ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hold the header's content visibility state before sliding it up. And slide down the content only when it was not visible.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ituvok/10/edit).

```
$(".fileHeader").on('click', function () {
    var content$ =  $(this).next(),
        isContentVisible = content$.is(':visible');

    $(".LST_Documents:visible").slideUp().promise().done(function () {
        if ( ! isContentVisible ) {
            content$.slideDown();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout a simple condition:

```
$(".fileheader").on('click', function() {    
    var next = $(this).next();
    if(next.is(':visible'))
    {
        next.slideUp();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".LST_Documents:visible").slideUp().promise().done(function() {
              next.slideDown();
        });
    }
});
```